# Regex to Replace the end of the Url

Tags: c#, regex

I have a url something that follows a pattern as below :

http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/MTUw12323gxNTAw/$(KGr123qF,!p0F123Q~~60_12.JPG?set_id=88123231232F

I need a regex to find and replace the end of the url _12.JPG with _14.JPG. So basically i need to capture the _[numbers only].JPG pattern and replace it with my value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var regex = new Regex(@"_\d+\.JPG");
var newUrl = regex.Replace(url, "_14.JPG");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
_[0-9]+\.JPG\?
```

works for the sample URL.  You didn't really mention whether you wanted the 
?set_id=88123231232F gone or not.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you shouldn't normally be concerned with periods anywhere else in the URL. It is possible, but the additional constraint of the jpg extension should limit anything returned with not much issue.

```
///_(\d?\d).jpg/ig
var regex = new Regex(@"_(\d?\d).[Jj][Pp][Gg]");
```

That will capture one or two numbers between an underscore and .jpg

I will double check this, but it should work for both one digit and two digits.